# WPF Resources Localization from webservice

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, rest, localization

I'm struggling with this issue. I have a webservice that retrieves all the possible labels (with keys) for my application. This labels may vary from culture to culture (en, fr, de, pt, etc).
My doubt is how can I create/fill a resource file for that culture and fill with those labels/keys?

Those labels are managed by a backend server, and I have a GET to a REST webservice to get those strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there are any best practices for this. You need to write a mini-framework that could do one of the things listed bellow:

1. [If using MVVM] You could put the labels on your view model and bind to them in XAML. Involves writing lots of properties even when using snippets. Also, lots of properties are a pain when binding.
2. [If using MVVM] A better design similar to 1 where you store the labels in a separate class which is a property in your view model. Let your imagination go wild, use singleton, caching, etc. This is the most dangerous approach.
3. You could create one (or more classes) like any view model (at least with INotifyPropertyChanged), store it as a XAML resource and bind to it, populate it when you want. More XAML when binding labels but does what you're asking for and it's easily readable for others.

In all the options listed above you can change locale at runtime with translation being effective immediately (assuming you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and bound label to take account of this), which you don't get with .resx and changing thread culture.

I would try all 3 as sample projects and see which would make a time-efficient way of manipulating label resources (adding, removing, changing, renaming them, and of course maintaining their contents).

Personally, I would go with 3. I listed the others just to be a little exhaustive.

Comment: I've found this extension: http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Localization%20providers&referringTitle=Documentation
I will give it also a try, but thanks for your possible solutions!

Comment: could you give a better example on nr 3?